# How to bring back custom notification sounds in Oreo

Tags: notifications, 8.0-oreo, custom-sounds

I upgraded to Oreo about a week ago and I've noticed that all my apps' alerts now sound like my SMS alert.

This means that I either get constantly bothered by unimportant notifications (It's your turn in a game!, etc.), or I miss important notifications like most SMSs, because now now unimportant and important notifications sound the same.

With the new notification channels I can set a custom sound manually, but the last thing I want to do is customise every single notification on my phone, and I also don't know where the sound files are for the original sounds. It's just too much work.

How can I get Oreo to behave like Nougat in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best solution, but set the SMS channel notification sound as something different instead of customising for each app?

Answer (score 0):

You may use Ultimate Notification Control in Gravity Bx with Xposed Framework. You can set per app vibrations and notification sounds there.